# Automatically save certain excel sheets (in an xlsm file) as .csv every 15 minutes

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am quite new to VBA. I have a spreadsheet which contains 20 worksheets. There is a macro which runs every 15 minutes which displays data on worksheets 5, 10, 15 and 20. I want to be able to automatically save the data in these worksheets in .csv format every 15 minutes.

The spreadsheet is called 'Events.xlsm'; the worksheets I want to save are Event Total, Event Total(2), Event Total(3) and Event Total(4). I have had an attempt to save one of the worksheets based on some other examples on this site. Not sure if I am on the right track.

```
Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()

Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SaveToDirectory As String

Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
Dim CurrentFormat As Long

CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.Events
CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.xlsm
' Store current details for the workbook
SaveToDirectory = "S:\test\"
For Each WS In Day Event.Worksheets
Sheets(WS.Event Total).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & ThisWorkbook.Events & "-" & WS.Event Total & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
ThisWorkbook.Activate

Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurrentWorkbook, FileFormat:=CurrentFormat
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
' Temporarily turn alerts off to prevent the user being prompted
'  about overwriting the original file.

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to the VBA community! Please edit your question to include what you have achieved so far in this endeavor.

Comment: Excel Macro is Event based, it cant auto trigger every 15 min, unless yr macro is keep running and never stop.

Comment: @EricK. - `Application.OnTime` with a loop and ending time statement can run a macro every 15 minutes.

Comment: See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information ... following on what @Jeeped comment :)

Comment: That is exactly what I use @ScottHoltzman

Comment: James - have you even googled  [excel vba to save a worksheet as a csv file?](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=excel%20vba%20to%20save%20a%20worksheet%20as%20a%20csv%20file%3F) - This is a **great** place to start. All things considered, it's a pretty easy element to add into your existing code.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman with ending loop, then will not able to work with excel right ?

Comment: @EricK. - Think `Do Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:15:00")) ... code, code, code ... Loop Until Now >= 5:00pm` type of thing

Comment: Added some code @ScottHoltzman based on some of those examples. Don't know if I'm on the right track. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sort of got there. There's a bunch of stuff to clean up. Rather than write a long tutorial, I just refactored the code and commented some of it for you.

**There is a caveat here:** CSV files are a very specific and unique *flat* format. This means, there can be only 1 sheet per file, no special formatting or anything like that. If there is, you need to clean it up before saving the csv.

```
Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim SaveToDirectory As String

' Store current details for the workbook
SaveToDirectory = "S:\test\"

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If Left(WS.Name, 10) = "Event Total" Then 'evaluate if its a sheet that needs to be saved

        Dim wbCopy As Workbook
        WS.Copy
        Set wbCopy = ActiveWorkbook

        'Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'turn this on once you are sure it will save the CSV correctly, even with a warning prompt
        With wbCopy
            .SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & ThisWorkbook.Name & "-" & WS.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
            .Close savechanges:=False
        End With
        'Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End If

Next

ThisWorkbook.Save 'a simple save will do here. no need to overwrite the workbook unless you want to

End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate that @Scott Holtzman. What does the "10" after WS.Name refer to?

Comment: Look up `Left` Function. It returns the 10 left characters from `WS.Name` or whatever the argument is

Comment: If this works for you @JamesAndrews, please mark as answered.

Comment: Hi @Scott Holtzman. Unfortunately when I run the macro I receive Compile error: Expected Function or variable, with ".Copy" highlighted.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Holtzman. That has worked. Very grateful for your assistance.